# Insert data in 2 tables for a categories system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am doing a practice of a small blog with php and sql and i need to insert data in 2 tables at the same time, for example when creating a new post selected their categories of that post and that these are shown in a different table called entries.

These are the 3 tables that I have created, in POSTS all the data of the posts is stored and in CATEGORIAS all the data of the categories is stored.

[image: IMAGE 1]

**TABLE: POST**

[image: IMAGE 2]

**TABLE: CATEGORIAS**

[image: IMAGE 3]

Then my question is how can I get the data inserted into the table of **entradas** and store the ID's of the publications and the ID's of the selected categories. For example, in this case the publication "El Oceano" has the category "Naturaleza".

**Example of the table: entradas**

[image: IMAGE 4]

CODE: db.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

CODE: posts.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'posts';
$categorias = selectAll('categorias');

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';
$body = '';

$posts = selectAll($table);

    
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
        
        
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "¡Necesitas subir una imagen!");
    }
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

    }


if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime eliminado correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime actualizado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
}
} 
?>
```

CODE: categorias.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validateCategoria.php');

$table = 'categorias';

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$name = '';
$body = '';
$topic_id = '';

$categorias = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $errors = validateCategoria($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria creada correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria eliminada correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria actualizada correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

}
} 
?>
```

Comment: So you have a `post` table, and a `post_categories` table, right? And you need to insert into `post`, get the `ID`, and then insert that into `post_categories` once for each category? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: *how can I get the data inserted into the table of entradas* Use SELECT. Use the data entered into inserted row as selection criteria.  `INSERT INTO a (val_a) VALUES ('A');` and then `INSERT INTO b (val_b,a_id) SELECT 'B', a.id FROM a WHERE a.val_a='A';`

Comment: @Chris Haas | Yes, I currently have 3 tables **posts**, **categorias**, and **entradas** I need that when I create a new post it shows me the ID of that post in the table **entradas** and the IDS of the selected categories.